# Include a link using PHP

Tags: php, variables, url, path, include

Today I'm trying to include a page in another one in PHP using the link instead of the path, so the code could look like this

```
include "http://localhost/mypage/myfile.php"
```

but it throws me the following error:

> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavoro\lang\en\login\home.php on line 10

I really don't know how to change these variable! I've tried using some line of code that I found also in this forum but nothing works. And another thing, I don't know which version of PHP I'm using.

Thanks for everyone who wants to help me

Comment: If the file is on your site you dont need the full url so try `include "mypage/myfile.php";` Remember its an instruction to PHP not Apache

Comment: But if i want to do like this i have to write all the path back, i mean, if the file from where i'm trying to include is in a subfolder and the file that i want to include is in the main folder i have to use `../` for indicate the main folder... now, if the folder where is the first file is a subfolder of a subfolder and so on is a mess use this `../` for locate the other file

Comment: `phpinfo();` in a `.php` file will show your PHP version. You could either use [set_​include_​path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) or the full path to the file to include `include "C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavoro\mypage\myfile.php"`

Answer (score 0):

The warning is generated because you are using a full `URL` for the file that you are including. This is NOT the right way because this way you are going to get some `HTML` from the webserver. Use:

```
require_once('mypage/myfile.php');  //your file name
```

so that webserver could EXECUTE the script and deliver its output, instead of just serving up the source code (your current case which leads to the warning).